# Page Load of aspx page called in jquery dialog not calling first time

Tags: jquery, dialog, load

I am opening a jquery dialog on button click.I am opening panel as dialog. In that panel there is iframe and in that iframe src I have called the new page.

I have initialized jquery dialog in page load as follows
    /* initialize dialog on page load*/

```
$(function(){
    $("#PanelTest").dialog(
    {                    
        minWidth: 500,
        minHeight: 500,
        autoOpen: false
    });    
});
```

In this function I am opening panel as dialog in this function

```
function OpenPopupTest()
{
    $("#PanelTest").dialog('open')
}
```

My panel is as follows

```
<asp:Panel ID="PanelTest" runat="server" Style="display: none; background-color: White;
    font-size: 12px;">
    <div id="DivTst" style="text-align: left; margin-top: 20px; margin-left: 10px">
        <iframe id="iframeTest" src="Test1.aspx" height="400px" width="400px"></iframe>
         <br />
    </div>
</asp:Panel>
```

This button is inside update panel.

In code behind on botton attribute I am calling the javascript function.        ButtonTest.Attributes.Add("onclick","OpenPopupTest()");

When I click on ButtonTest button popup is opening. In Test1.aspx there is 1 textbox which I want to fill in page load event of Test1.aspx. I have written code for putting value in textbox in page load event of Test1.aspx. When I debugged the code I found that this code is being called but when popup opens there is no value displayed in textbox.
I think that when the page in which panel is present loads at that time page called in iframe ie. Test1.aspx is also getting loaded. I want to pass 1 value from parent page to child page (Test1.aspx) through  which value in textbox is being filled.

Please let me know how to achieve this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does it have to be an iframe? I would think it would be easier and a better soloution to use ajax to load the content, and on ajax succes open the dialog.

Comment: Can you please let me know how to use ajax to load the content and how to open the dialog on ajax success.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using iframes i would do a normal ajax request.

So i would do:

```
function OpenPopupTest()
{
    //Link is clicked, get data, and open popup when data is ready
    $.get('Test1.aspx', function(data) {
      $('#DivTst').html(data);
      $("#PanelTest").dialog('open');
    });
}

function RefreshPopupTest()
{
    //Link is clicked, update data
    $.get('Test1.aspx', function(data) {
      $('#DivTst').html(data);
    });
}

function OpenPopupIFrameTest()
{
    //Link is clicked, update the iframe and open idalog
   document.getElementById("iframeTest").contentDocument.location.reload(true);
   $("#PanelTest").dialog('open');
}


function RefreshIFrameTest()
{
    //Link is clicked, update the iframe
    document.getElementById("iframeTest").contentDocument.location.reload(true);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I was able to open popup through this code. But now I have another issue. In my Test1.aspx page I have 1 TextBox and 4 buttons. There is some server side code on click of 2 buttons. Popup is opening correctly but when I am clicking on any button then the parent page is disappearing and in place of parent page popup is being opened like it happens in window.open. Any ideas about this.

Comment: Well thats because you don't have an iframe any more. What are the functions, are they something that can be done on the "parent" page? Else you could update the iframe on dialog open. If you descreibe what they do, ill try to make some example code, or edit the code to update the iframe :)

Comment: I cant write the server side code in parent page. Server side code has to be in the child page ie. Test1.aspx. Is there a way we can update the iframe on dialog open.

Comment: Well they dont have to be. What does the function on Test1.aspx do? If they are a form, or something else they would work perfectly as is. I updated the code with some more examples :)